# Screen gets a heavy green tint once booted to desktop

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, monitor, colors, projector

I recently changed my monitor from a TV to a projector using an HDMI cable. Now whenever I boot the PC, the colors stay correct during the UEFI screen and the boot splash until it turns green once loading the desktop.

I'm using an Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti with proprietary drivers.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to play around with `xrandr`, e.g. disabling and enabling the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. I just rebooted my projector while the desktop is loaded. I suppose I'll just have to reboot the projector once the desktop loads.

Answer (score 0):

Green tint with Nvidia Graphics cards
correction

Open google search engine
Top left corner.  Click "CUSTOMISE & CONTROL TAB"
Settings
Advanced.
USE HARDWARE ACCELERATOR WHEN AVAILABLE....TURN OFF.
Restart
This will cure your green tint